# Remove decimals from a Float column

Tags: python, floating-point, format

shocked beyond belief how difficult this is turning out to be. All I can find are suggestions to change the format of the column to 'int' but I need to keep the comma thousand separators and changing the format to int gets rid of them. THEN i can't find anything on how to add comma separators to an int column. any ideas? really is nothing for me to share in addition to above in terms of what i've tried.

Comment: Please read [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). There's not much help we can give without _any_ detail on where you're starting from. I'm surprised you're finding this so difficult. Searching for ["format float with thousands separators"](//www.google.com/search?q=format+float+with+thousands+separators) should tell you how to keep the thousands separators. ["format float without decimals"](//www.google.com/search?q=python+format+float+without+decimals) should tell you how to remove the decimals. Combine those two, and you have your answer.

Comment: humans and computers are good at different things!  when you're getting started it can be difficult to delineate these factors.  learning about different data-types and when to apply them will help as would the internal and external representations of these types.  programming languages have some fundamental building blocks you need to understand to make much progress

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Format your floats...in a string format?

```
my_string = '{:,.0f}'. format(my_number) 

E.g.:
x = 1000.00
'{:,.0f}'. format(x)-> 1,000
```

Which gives you what you want...something you can print with commas. 0f sets to 0 precision. (for how many decimal places)